# MS Access 2002/VBA - join a number of lookup tables to main query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Consider:

```
contact
=======
contact_id, not null
name, not null
electorate_id, null allowed
member_type_id, null allowed

member_types
===========+
member_type_id
member_type

electorates
===========
electorate_id
electorate
```

These are tables I wish to use to populate a form.  I have tried this a few ways, but the query returns no data:

```
SELECT contact_id, name, member_type, electorate
FROM contact LEFT JOIN member_types 
ON contacts.member_type_id=member_types.member_type_id,
contacts LEFT JOIN electorates
ON contacts.electorate_id=electorates.electorate_id
```

Also:

```
"SELECT contact_id, name, member_types.member_type, electorates.electorate
FROM contacts, member_types, electorates
WHERE contacts.contact_id=" & contact_id & " 
and electorates.electorate_id=contacts.electorate_id
and member_types.member_type_id = contacts.member_type_id"
```

Both of these fail.  Can someone suggest a query that works please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT contact_id, name, member_type, electorate
FROM contact 
LEFT JOIN member_types ON contact.member_type_id=member_types.member_type_id
LEFT JOIN electorates ON contact.electorate_id=electorates.electorate_id
```

Don't re-specify the **contact** table in row 4. Also you have **contacts** in the ON clauses, not **contact**.

Hopefully LEFT JOINS are supported in ACCESS 2002.

Also, your second query will only work if both the electorate_id and member_id are set.  That's why you need the LEFT JOIN.